# Method generics different interface

Tags: c#, methods, interface

Why I cannot use **generic methods** with interfaces like that?

> Interfaces for my parameters

```
public interface IBaseParam {
    string Name { get; }
}


public interface IComplexParam : IBaseParam {
    string P1 { get; }
    string P2 { get; }
}
```

> Class that use generic interfaces

```
public interface ILauncherCommand {
    void launch<T>(T parameters) where T : IBaseParam;
}



public class BaseCommand : ILauncherCommand {
    string Name { get; }

    public void launch<T>(T parameters) where T : IBaseParam {

    }
}



public class ComplexCommand : ILauncherCommand {
    string Name { get; }

    public void launch<T>(T parameters) where T : IComplexParam {

    }
}
```

**ComplexCommand.launch** is where compiler show problem (CS0425).
IComplexParam is inherited from IBaseParam, so the contract must be valid.

I can compile only if I declare a **generic class**, but I want to use a generic method instead a full generic class

> The code BELOW works, **but is a generic class**

```
public interface ILauncherCommand<T> where T : IBaseParam {
    void launch(T parameters);
}



public class BaseCommand : ILauncherCommand<IBaseParam> {
    string Name { get; }

    public void launch(IBaseParam parameters) {

    }
}



public class ComplexCommand : ILauncherCommand<IComplexParam> {
    string Name { get; }

    public void launch(IComplexParam parameters) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic methods force you to use Invariant type which means you have to provide exactly what you specified.

What you are looking for is to enable Covariance type to allow more derived types to be used. This can only be done at class level:

Note that the `<in T>` is the way to specify covariance.

```
public interface ILauncherCommand<in T> where T : IBaseParam
{
    void launch(T parameters);
}

public class BaseCommand<T> : ILauncherCommand<T> where T : IBaseParam  
{
    string Name { get; }

    public void launch(T parameters)
    {
    }
}

public class ComplexCommand<T> : ILauncherCommand<T> where T : IComplexParam
{
    string Name { get; }

    public void launch(T parameters)
    {
    }
}
```

In this specific case, note that the `<in >` is optional as covariance is automatic.

You can get further info here:  [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: Ok, so my second implementation, generic class, (see OP) is the only one usable. Thanks